# Why can't I use a Java map to change the type of object in my stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm dealing with a web-service which loads ApplicationResponse objects n at a time. I want to to make a stream which will allow me to consume all of them without having to worry about paging, hence my (incomplete) use of Java streams.

[image: Can't change type!]

I've got a stream which generates the page numbers. I wanted to map those numbers to streams of responses using a function I had previously written.

The trouble is, it seems to want my arrow function to return an int and not the Stream which was what I was expecting.

How can I rewrite this expression so that the map operation works?

Comment: Someone with that much reputation should normally know better than to post a screenshot of code. Especially one that forces users to kiss the screen to make out anything in it.

Comment: Please post actual code. not an image.

Comment: Use `mapToObj()` instead of `map()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `IntStream.map()` methods takes `IntUnaryOperator` as argument. As you can see in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html):

> public interface IntUnaryOperator
>
> Represents an operation on a single int-valued operand that produces an int-valued result. This is the primitive type specialization of UnaryOperator for int.

this type of Function consumes `int` and produces `int`.

As suggested by nickb, you should use the `mapToObj` method, which accepts `IntFunction` argument types ([Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html)):

> public interface IntFunction
>
> Represents a function that accepts an int-valued argument and produces a result. This is the int-consuming primitive specialization for Function.

Those can produce any type of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `IntStream` which `.map` method is expected to return also InstStream, in case you want to convert IntStream to usual Stream of objects you either should use `.boxed()` which will return you Stream of Integer, or call `mapToObj()` which will map your ints to some other objects using specified mapping function.